# Stata 16.0 Integration with Python

Tags: stata

Stata 16.0+ allows to integrate python scripts within Stata and the dofile.
Why does Stata 16.0+ fails to access Python? Using the following command, Stata should recognize automatically the presence of python:

```
python
```

or

```
python query
```

> failed to load the shared library  C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7...\python37.dll.

Answer (score 0):

Here are three solutions, the third was preferred for simplicity:

1. The default folder *WindowsApps* has special security access permission which can be [modified](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/what-is-windows-apps-hidden-folder-and-why-cant-i/40a60508-c409-422a-af92-bd51fe5a4ca9).
2. Relocate your Python installation to another folder
3. Download another distribution such as [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) to use within Stata

> python search

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Python environments found:  
 C:\Users\Username\anaconda3\python.exe
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> set python_exec C:\Users\Username\anaconda3\python.exe, permanently